# AudioStream IP Address

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a wireless audio connection between two android devices. So I found `AudioStream` class, and I have the partial code like this:

```
public  String getMobileIP() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                    .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ipaddress = inetAddress .getHostAddress().toString();
                    return ipaddress;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("tag", "Exception in Get IP Address: " + ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}


 public void Connect()
 {
 String ipaa=getMobileIP();
 InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName(ipaa);
 AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(local);     <<----- exception
 ...
 ...
 }
```

I want both phones to connect by voice using the `AudioStream` so that both people can talk and hear each other like a `walkie-talkie`.

I decide to use the mobile network IP address of the phone (Not the WiFi address), but when I do that the above code crashes when I use that to create the `AudioStream`.

I want the users to be able to talk to each other weather they are on WiFi or not (using mobile network).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html) says exception occurs if the address cannot be bound or a problem occurs during binding. I think you could accomplish through Wi-fi because you were in the same network. However, when using mobile data IPs of ISPs (Internet Service Providers) might not see each other (it depends on ISP). Hence connection cannot be established.

Obvious solution is that your voice should go through some server where both clients can see it.